# WordPress Contact Form 7. Заблокировать поле формы обратной связи

Tags: wordpress

Есть динамические поля, в которые подставляются данные авторизованного на сайте пользователя. Как заблокировать содержимое этого поля от редактирования при открытии формы пользователем?

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте вот так

```html
<input type="text" readonly>
```

Вот тут более подробно https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_readonly.asp

Comment: Там про CF7: Нет? Тогда это НЕ ответ на задачу ТСа.

Answer (score 0):

> Как заблокировать содержимое этого поля от редактирования при открытии формы пользователем?

Добавить в шаблон поля формы `readonly`.
Напр. `[text* your-name readonly]`